# How to add a column to pyspark df, the data format should be a list, and come from grouped data from the raw table

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark, not sure if there's an easy way to do this.

I have a df with people's interests for example:

| name | interest |
| --- | --- |
| A | gym |
| A | food |
| A | games |
| B | games |

from this df, I would like to create a new one like following:

| name | interests |
| --- | --- |
| A | gym;food;games |
| B | games |

Can someone help with this? Sorry in advance if i didn't explain clear enough of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html) and [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("name").agg(
  F.concat_ws(";", F.collect_list("interest")
             ).alias("interest")).show(truncate=False)
```

prints:

```
+----+--------------+
|name|interest      |
+----+--------------+
|A   |gym;food;games|
|B   |games         |
+----+--------------+
```

Remember to assign it back to a new dataframe

- `concat_ws`: Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single string column, using the given separator.
- `collect_list`:

Answer (score 0):

```
schema = X.schema
X_pd = X.toPandas()
_X = spark.createDataFrame(X_pd,schema=schema)
del X_pd
```